# raw socket error with sendto: no error code [was: raw socket error with sendto: no such device]

Tags: c++, linux, raw-sockets

im stuck  with sending a raw ethernet frame.

[edit]
I found some errors.
1. It has to be AF_PACKET in the socket call.
2. AF_PACKET doesnt have an option SOCK_PACKET, but SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_RAW

With SOCK_DGRAM wireshark captures a malformed LLC packet.
But with SOCK_RAW no error message and no captured packet.

i dont find whats really going wrong.
[/edit]

the code:

```
if ((ethernet_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1)
    cout << "Ethernet Socket: "<< strerror(errno) << endl;

struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
socket_address.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;
socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);
socket_address.sll_ifindex=if_nametoindex("eth0");
socket_address.sll_hatype   = 1; // ARPHRD_ETHER
socket_address.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_OTHERHOST;
socket_address.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;
memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr,dest_mac_addr,ETH_ALEN);

int send_result = 0;

char *opt=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
strcpy(opt,"eth0");

if(setsockopt(ethernet_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, opt, 4)==-1)
    cout << "Could not bind socket to device: " << strerror(errno) << endl;

if ((send_result  
= sendto(ethernet_socket, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,  
    (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address)))==-1){
        cout << "sendto error: "<< strerror(errno) << endl;
        return send_result;
}
```

regards
Ck

Comment: Are you running as root?  Last time I looked (years ago) you had to have privileges to use raw sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution how this works. 
i took a look at the source code of the Linux program PackEth.

the following code works for me.

```
if ((ethernet_socket = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1)
    cout << "Ethernet Socket: "<< strerror(errno) << endl;  //errorhandling

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strncpy (ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name) - 1);
ifr.ifr_name[sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)-1] = '\0';


if (ioctl(ethernet_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) {
    cout << "No such interface:"<< strerror(errno) << endl;
    close(ethernet_socket);
}

ioctl(ethernet_socket, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
if ( (ifr.ifr_flags & 0x1) == 0) {
    cout << "Interface is down: "<< strerror(errno) << endl;
    close(ethernet_socket);
}

ioctl(ethernet_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);


memset(&socket_address, 0, sizeof (socket_address));
socket_address.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
socket_address.sll_ifindex   = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
socket_address.sll_protocol  = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

if ((raw_send = sendto(ethernet_socket, buffer, size_payload+14,0,(struct     sockaddr*)     
                           &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address)))==-1){
    cout << "sendto error: "<< strerror(errno) << endl;
    return raw_send;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man 7 packet
```

"SOCK_RAW packets are passed to and from the device driver **without any changes in the packet data**.  When receiving a packet, the address is still parsed and passed in a standard sockaddr_ll address structure.  **When transmitting a packet,  the user supplied buffer should contain the physical layer header**.  That packet is then queued unmodified to the network driver of the interface defined by the destination address.  Some device drivers always  add  other headers.

SOCK_DGRAM operates on a slightly higher level. The physical header is removed before the packet is passed to the user. **Packets sent through a SOCK_DGRAM packet socket get a suitable physical layer header based on the information in the sockaddr_ll destination address before they are queued**."

Comment: with physical layer header the fields preamble, SFD and CRC are addressed or am i mistaken?

Comment: If by that you mean, does using the SOCK_DGRAM option generate proper values for the physical layer header, then yes, it should. Also, I've noticed that you `malloc()` 4 bytes, then `strcpy()` `"eth0"` into it. `"Eth0"`, being a C-string, is NUL-terminated, and so it needs 5 bytes to hold it. And if you've commited to `cout`, which is C++, you should probably use the C++ way of allocating memory on the heap, which is `new/delete` (as opposed to C's `malloc()/free()`.